# How do you call a method from a model, in the Django Shell?

Tags: python, django, shell, django-1.5

I have a simple model like

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def getJustDomainName(self):
        """ for example, if website is http://www.someweb.com/index.html, return someweb.com """
        return '0'; #TODO
```

I didn't actually implement the method `getJustDomainName` name here because I am just using this as an example.

I want to test this method in the Django Shell. So I tried doing something like;

```
Publisher.objects.all()[0].getJustDomainName
```

but in return I get

```
<bound method Publisher.getJustWebsiteName of <Publisher: Publisher(#1): RandomHouse>>
```

which is not what I'm expecting. I'm expecting (and desiring) a result that returns what the function returns.

How do I call this model method properly from the shell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're not calling the method. You need to do:

```
Publisher.objects.all()[0].getJustDomainName()
```

notice the parenthesis `()` at the end there. The way you're doing it now just prints the method itself (`<bound method...` etc. isn't an error. It simply tells you about the method, instead of running it which you do with `()` like you'd do with any function).

**p.s.**

I'm guessing you're a javascript (or something) developer who's new to python (you're question regards very basic python, you're using camel-casing and a needless `;` at the end of a line). The `;` is usually fine, but know that the convention in python is to use `_` for functions and methods, i.e. `get_just_domain_name` instead of `getJustDomainName` (and I would've got rid of that `just` entirely, it's redundant). Both are valid, it's just a common convention of the language.